# Cannot get a IP address from DDWRT wireless access point connected to Opnsense

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, dd-wrt, opnsense

I have been setting up my home lab with Opnsense on a HP T620, TP Link managed switch and my old TP Link Archer running DDWRT as a WAP.

I can connect to the WIFI but all the IP addresses are assigned in the range of the LAN which is 192.168.1.*

I have set up VLANs on Opnsense which are assigning the correct static IPs when devices are attached to the switch.

I cannot seem to get the correct static IP addresses when connecting via the WAP, any IP addresses at all or any internet connection. I can connect to the Virtual AP I have created though.

I created a Virtual Interface on WLAN0 which would be wlan0.1.

In the switch config tab on DDWRT I created a VLAN on the WAN port and checked tagged.

In the networking tab I have assigned the correct tag number (50) to wlan0.1.

I created a bridge and assigned that bridge to the wlan0.1 interface.

I then gave wlan0.1 the correct starting IP which would be 192.168.50.*

Finally I have created a DHCP for the bridge.

When I try to connect to wlan0.1 it takes a really long time to connect and when it is connected there is not internet access and I do not get an IP address at assigned at all.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on? I am on a TP Link Archer c7 v2.

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that VLANs on the Atheros processor were not working on this make model but am not sure. Any guidance would be gratefully received.